# Return int from MVC Action with Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, actionresult, ajax.beginform

Whats the simplest way of just returning an **int** from an **Ajax MVC Action** call?

I am currently trying:

```
public ContentResult Create(MyModel model)
{
    return Content("1");
}

using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create",
        new AjaxOptions {
            OnComplete = "function(data) { alert(data); }"
        }))
```

I get alert `[object Object]`. How do I get the int value? Or if possible return the int directly instead of having to use a ContentResult?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
public JsonResult Create(MyModel model)
{
    return Json(new { Result = 1 });
}

using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create",
        new AjaxOptions {
            OnComplete = "function(data) { alert(data.get_response().get_object().Result); }"
        }))
```